# Fail to startup openJMS version 0.7.7-beta

Tags: startup, openjms

I have download the latest openJMS version(0.7.7-beta-1) and configure the JAVA_HOME AND OPENJMS_HOME as per instruction

> http://openjms.sourceforge.net/adminguide/install.html>

ISSUE: Fail to startup openJMS server using startup.bat or openJMS run command

I didn't change anything else, does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

<<>>:
C:\Program Files\openjms-0.7.7-beta-1\bin>openjms run
Using OPENJMS_HOME: C:\Program Files\openjms-0.7.7-beta-1
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1
Using CLASSPATH:    C:\Program Files\openjms-0.7.7-beta-1\lib\derby-10.1.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\openjms-0.7.7-beta-1\lib\openjms-0.7.7-beta-1.jar;C:\Program Files\openjms-0.7.7-beta-1\lib\openjms-tools-0.7.7-beta-1.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\openjms-0.7.7-beta-1\db
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\openjms-0.7.7-beta-1\db

Comment: Did you introduce their path in environment path ?

Answer (score 0):

> aused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\openjms-0.7.7-beta-1\db

As you can see the space in the path is a problem because it tries to find "Files..." directory.

Try to use one of this notes for Windows users on 64-bit systems:

- Progra~1 = 'Program Files'
- Progra~2 = 'Program Files (x86)'

So for example: `setx OPENJMS_HOME "C:\Progra~1\openjms-0.7.7-beta-1"`